# Need help understanding output from grep with pattern file

Tags: regex, file-io, grep, pattern-matching

I'm writing to respectfully request help understanding the grep (Mac OS X Mavericks) example below.

file to grep:  **2c2d2rh**

cat dog rat 
cat dog rat

pattern file: **1c1d1rv**

cat
dog
rat

$grep -f1c1d1rv 2c2d2rh  produces

**cat dog rat**
**cat dog rat**

where bold font simulates --color=auto.

The grep man page says the -f option obtains patterns from FILE, one per line, so I'm expecting

**cat** dog rat
**cat** dog rat
cat **dog** rat
cat **dog** rat
cat dog **rat**
cat dog **rat**

where bold font indicates matches by my logic. Shouldn't grep read 'cat' in 1c1d1rv and match the two 'cat' lines in 2c2d2rh and move on to 'dog' and 'rat'? I don't understand why grep only produces two output lines rather than six in this example and would be very grateful for an explanation.

Xiexie,
Dai Deqi

Answer (score 0):

From grep manual:

> -f file, --file=file
>                Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.  Empty pattern lines
>                match every input line.  Newlines are not considered part of a pattern.  If
>                file is empty, nothing is matched.

The first sentence means that grep looks for *all* the patterns in the file and highlights *every* match (unlike the "normal" behavior of grep which looks for the first match in each line and ignores the rest).

Comment: There is no difference between reading patterns from a file and adding them with `-e pat`, compare the `-f` output with `grep -e cat -e dog -e rat`.

Comment: @Thor right, the idea is that you compare separately against each one of the patterns, and not "bail out" when the first match is found.

Comment: @aflasin (and Thor).  Your explanations were very helpful.  Thank you both!

Comment: @alfasin: I see what you mean, I thought that "bailing out" on the first match per line would default behavior, but it does not seem to be. Or am I overlooking something?